# How to bind ts variable to html?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to bind a ts variable to html file, i tried so many way but i could not. Maybe I am setting the value in ts file wrong. Here is the template code:

```
<div class="md-dialog-container">
    <h2>{{message}}</h2>
    <button type="submit" class="button-style btn btn-info" (click)="closeDialog()">Close</button>
</div>
```

And here is the ts file of that template:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-error-dialog',
  templateUrl: './error-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error-dialog.component.css']
})
export class ErrorDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  message: string;

  constructor(private dialogRef:MatDialogRef<ErrorDialogComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {
    this.message = data;
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  closeDialog() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
    console.log(this.message);
  }
}
```

As you see I am getting the *message* value as parameter. When I print it to console when I am closing the dialog, it is printing correct, but I could not show it in template page. How can I solve this issue ?
I have tried *this.message* instead of just *message* in html as well but it also did not work.

As you see below, console.log is working correct but on popup it shows object-object
[image]

Comment: What is your `data` that you are retrieving? Are you sure its a string? `[Object Object]` is an indicator that an object has been arbitrarily converted to a string with `toString()`, so the value in `message` isn't a string.  You should assign `data.string` if you want the string inside the object to be set to `message`, actually.

Comment: @somethinghere yes its worked thanks man. if you write it as answer i can accept it.

Comment: I have just done that, there are two solutions actually. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your console log, the value at `message` is not a string, but on object shaped like this:

```
{ string: "My String" }
```

So when it gets converted to `string` using `toString()`, you get `[Object object]` as an output. So where you assign `this.message = data`, you should actually do `this.message = data.string`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-error-dialog',
  templateUrl: './error-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error-dialog.component.css']
})
export class ErrorDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  message: string;

  constructor(private dialogRef:MatDialogRef<ErrorDialogComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {
    // Change made below, so your variable is of type string, not any
    this.message = data.string;
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  closeDialog() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
    console.log(this.message);
  }
}
```

Otherwise, in your template, you could also do `{{message.string}}`:

```
<div class="md-dialog-container">
    <!-- Change made to read the value in the object, not the object itself -->
    <h2>{{message.string}}</h2>
    <button type="submit" class="button-style btn btn-info" (click)="closeDialog()">Close</button>
</div>
```

That useful if you expect that you will be updating the `message` object with a new object, and keep everything in sync.

Answer (score 2):

The data you pass is in the format of `data: {string: string}`, which reads as "`data` is an `object` with a property of `string` that has the type `string`".
If you want to show `string` property inside your template you need to access it via `message.string`.

```
<h2>{{message.string}}</h2>
```

If you want to show the entire object, you can use angular's `json` pipe:

```
<pre>{{message | json}}</pre>
```

This will print: `{string: "The text you passed"}`.

If you are only interested in the `string` property in the first place, you may want to alter it in the constructor directly.

```
this.message = data.string;
```

and print it via

```
<h2>{{message}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing binding incorrectly. You received object and it will not display directly.

You need to bind with its key.

```
<h2>{{message.string}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try,

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.message = data;
}
```

Comment: data is not being resolved on ngOnIt method. It only exist in constructor.